# TypeError in JavaScript with forEach of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, loops, object, foreach

I am trying to fix an error with my code - the issue has been caused by a Type Error with the error message:

```
test.js:89 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at printResults (test.js:89)
    at test.js:105
```

Here is the code:

```
const phones = [{
    name: "iPhone XS", brand: "Apple", cost: 43, data: "500MB", minutes: "Unlimited", texts: "Unlimited"
},
    {
        name: "iPhone 11", brand: "Apple", cost: 64, data: "90GB", minutes: "Unlimited", texts: "Unlimited"
    },
    {
        name: "Galaxy S10", brand: "Samsung", cost: 30, data: "20GB", minutes: "Unlimited", texts: "Unlimited"
    },
    {
        name: "Galaxy S10", brand: "Samsung", cost: 65, data: "Unlimited", minutes: "Unlimited", texts: "Unlimited"
    },
    {
        name: "Galaxy A10", brand: "Samsung", cost: 11.99, data: "500MB", minutes: 250, texts: "Unlimited"
    },
    {
        name: "Galaxy S9", brand: "Samsung", cost: 31, data: "20GB", minutes: "Unlimited", texts: "Unlimited"
    },
    {
        name: "StarTAC 130", brand: "Motorola", cost: 3, data: "0MB", minutes: 200, texts: 500
    },
    {
        name: "Pixel 3A", brand: "Google", cost: 23, data: "4GB", minutes: "Unlimited", texts: "Unlimited"
    },
    {
        name: "Xperia 10", brand: "Sony", cost: 30, data: "20GB", minutes: "Unlimited", texts: "Unlimited"
    },
    {
        name: "P30", brand: "Huawei", cost: 27.99, data: "500MB", minutes: 500, texts: "Unlimited"
    }];






// Functions

function getUserPreferences() {

    // These are asking the user for entry of the data into the system.
        const userPrompt = [
        {
            phoneBrand: prompt("Enter a brand name") 
        },

        {
            phoneCost: prompt("Enter a monthly cost") 
        },

        {
            phoneData: prompt("Enter the amount of data") 
        },

        {
            phoneMins: prompt("How many minutes?") 
        },

        {
            phoneTexts: prompt("How many texts?") 
        },



        ]

}

function getMatchingPlans(phoneBrand, phoneCost, phoneData, phoneMins, phoneTexts) {

    // This is then filtering the object of phones to match what the user has entered into the system.

    const matchingPhones = phones.filter(function(phone) {
        if(phone.brand===phoneBrand && phone.cost.toString()<=phoneCost && phone.data<=phoneData && phone.minutes.toString()<=phoneMins && phone.texts.toString()<=phoneTexts) {
                return true;
    }
     return false;

})

}

function printResults() {

    // This is then displaying data in the system.

        const returnPhones = document.querySelector("#returnPhones");

        matchingPlans.forEach(function(phone) {

        const newList = document.createElement("ul");
        newList.textContent=phone.name;
        returnPhones.appendChild(newList);

})


}




const userPrefs = getUserPreferences();
const matchingPlans = getMatchingPlans(userPrefs);
printResults(matchingPlans);
```

Your help is much appreciated! I am simply trying to get the program to match the user's preferences to a mobile phone which is stored in the phones object, and then display to the user in the DOM. Previously without functions this worked, I am just trying to restructure this with functions.

Comment: `getMatchingPlans` never returns anything, so the result of calling it is `undefined`.

Comment: You're also not declaring `matchingPlans` as a parameter in `printResults`, so `printResults` uses `matchingPlans` from the outer scope, which isn't best practice. You're passing it as an argument, so declare a parameter to receive it: `function printResults(matchingPlans) {`.

Answer (score 0):

the error is irrelevant of type script, you are calling forEach on an undefined value. so based on your code matchingPlans is undefined in the `printResults` function

The other issue is you are calling `printResults(matchingPlans);` but your `printResults` doesn't accept any parameter

The other issue is seems you expect `getMatchingPlans` to return an array, but you are returning boolean

The other issue is not using arrow function, so

```
const matchingPhones = phones.filter(function(phone) {
```

become

```
const matchingPhones = phones.filter((phone) => {
```

and other places